# How do I update a specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm practising react with a simple task master app, where I add each user input as a new task in an array of tasks. In the app, I have Add, Delete, and Update buttons.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the update function, it updates the last index of the array instead of the specific index I clicked.

Here is my JSX

```
 const JsxElement = task.map((eachTask, index) => {
    return (
        <Fragment key={index}>
            <div key={index} className="table-data-container">
                <div className="item-data">{eachTask}</div>
                <div className="item-data">{date}</div>
                <div className="item-data">
                    <div className="btn-data-container">
                        <div className="btn-data">
                            <div className="btn" onClick={() => deleteTask(index)}>Delete</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="btn-data">
                            <div className="btn" onClick={() => UpdateTaskBtn(eachTask, index)}>Update</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            {task.length - 1 === index &&
                <div className="input-update-container">
                    <div className="input-area">
                        <input
                            ref={inputRef}
                            type="text"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="btn-update-add-container">
                        {update ?
                            <div className="btn-add" onClick={() => handleTaskUpdate(eachTask, index)}>Update
                                Task</div>
                            :
                            <div className="btn-add" onClick={handleTask}>Add Task</div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </Fragment>

    )
})
```

The first update button function prepares the input, sets the task to be updated and makes the update button visible. The second one is where I want the update action to happen once clicked.

```
function UpdateTaskBtn(eachTask) {
    inputRef.current.value = eachTask
    setUpdate(true)
}
function handleTaskUpdate(e, index) {
    const list = [...task]
    list[index] = inputRef.current.value
    setTask(list)


    inputRef.current.value = ""
    setUpdate(false)
}
```

I want to be able to set the task to the specific index I want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this line of code

```
 {task.length - 1 === index &&
```

you are checking if the index is the last index , so you are passing the last index to the handleTaskUpdate function. so you can define a updateIndex state

```
const [updateIndex,setUpdateIndex] = useState()
```

then your function should look like this

```
function UpdateTaskBtn(eachTask,index) {
    inputRef.current.value = eachTask
    setUpdateIndex(index)
    setUpdate(true)
}
function handleTaskUpdate(e, index) {
    const list = [...task]
    list[updateIndex] = inputRef.current.value
    setTask(list)


    inputRef.current.value = ""
    setUpdate(false)
}
```

do not forget to pass index to UpdateTaskBtn function in onClick event

Comment: Thanks, and give you feedback if it works.

Comment: This actually worked, I forget I needed to pass the index I got from the UpdateTaskBtn function first. Some how, I thought since the handleTaskUpdate has an index passed already, I could make use of it which was why I got the updated set to the last array. Thanks alot

Comment: Please how do I mark this as Answered, I'm new here.

Comment: @TombrownAnuma https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147533

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function handleTaskUpdate(e, index) {
    const value = inputRef.current.value
    const updatedTasks = task.map((task, i) => i === index ? value : task)
    setTask(updatedTasks)

    inputRef.current.value = ""
    setUpdate(false)
}
```

Comment: I think I have written similar code before, did not work.